# Getting Input From HTML And Storing It In A File (Static Website)

Tags: javascript, html, input, static

I am trying to make a simple form submission in a GitHub Repository.
Basically what I want to do is take the input of an HTML  Tag and then store it in another local file such as another HTML file or a text file without a back-end.
I understand that there was a saveAs function within JavaScript (however I read that it had been discontinued due to security reasons). Once I get the data stored in a file I would call it in the HTML page with the < embed > tag to show it on the page. So basically I want the Input on the page, and then when it is appended to the file, to show up on the same page again when the page is refreshed. My reason for doing this is to make a make-shift Google WorkSpace-like page for my production studio.
Here's a visual of what I want to do:

HTML PAGE:

*Embedded File Contents (externalfile.html) Go Here.*

Input: `Input Goes Here`
`Submit`

When Submit is pressed, it takes the contents within the "Input Goes here" box and appends it to "externalfile.html", then when the page is refreshed, it shows the updated content above the form.

I am not well-versed in JavaScript but I know JQuery a Good bit from making a few websites with Wix, but I do not know much native JavaScript nor it's functions. Any advice would be helpful. :) Thank you. I would be adding multiple input boxes and such on the page.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Hello and welcome to StackOverflow!

Now, if I got your question right, you want to append something to a file and read this file without using any backend? Then I must disappoint you, because there is no way JavaScript allows this, since it would be a tremendous security risk. The reason is, because any malicious JavaScript code on any webpage then could not only create malware files on your PC and dragging it to some start up folder, but also they would be able to read all the files and documents on your machine (without your knowledge!). So I think you see where the problem is.

For your task I recommend you using some kind of backend (i.e. NodeJS, PHP) and make things work with API requests and asynchronous JavaScript. Or you could serve your site with an ExpressJS backend and statically fetch the request and append its contents to a file. Then of course send an HTML file back with all the inputs the user made. The choice is yours.

Cheers